# Remove horizontal spacing when using position:relative in navigation bar

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to create a php navigation bar.  I've come up with a nice looking scheme using the following code:

css:

```
a.navbar:link    { color:#AAAAFF; text-shadow:none; 
             padding: 5px 12px; white-space:nowrap; font-size:15px;}
a.navbar:visited { color:#AAAAFF; text-shadow: #4444FF 0.0px 0.0px 2px}
a.navbar:hover   { color:#CCCCCC; background:#444488;  } 
a.navbar:active  { color:grey; }
a.navbar {padding:none; font-size:15px;}

span.leftbraces { font-size:25pt; padding: 0px 0px; 
    position:relative; right:-9px;  bottom:-3.75px;}
span.rightbraces { font-size:25pt; padding: 0px 0px; 
    position:relative; left:-9px;  bottom:-3.75px;}
```

php:

```
<?php
echo "<center>";
$links = array('Home'=>'index.htm', 'Site Map'=>'sitemap.htm');
$leftbrace = "<span class=leftbraces>[</span>";
$rightbrace = "<span class=rightbraces>]</span>";
foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
    echo "$leftbrace<a class=navbar href=\"$value\">$key</a>$rightbrace";
}
echo "</center>";
?>
```

and html:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<?php include 'navbar.test.php';?>
</html>
```

How can I eliminate the space between the braces without giving up the nice tightly-fitting background padding?  The `<table>` tag I've included is not necessary, it was just my latest attempt to get this to work.

[image: screenshot showing spacing issue]

[ Home ] I want to get rid of this space [ Site Map ]

[image: screenshot showing highlighting]

but I want to keep the tight fit of the highlighting

Comment: Your markup is very not good, which I'm sure is contributing to your problem(s).

Comment: Fair comment - are you just referring to the formatting/whitespace within the code?  That's a result of sloppy hacking trying to get this to work.  But if there's other bad form sitting around, I wouldn't mind a tip on what to fix.

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with it. Your *markup* is not correct. For instance, you're using a `table` for layout, which is discouraged, you've got stray `</p></span>` at the end of the first line, which both seem out of place and that kind of markup outside of the `td` is not valid, and `center` is deprecated and should avoided. Checkout this [A List Apart tutorial](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/) for a better, more modern way of doing what you want.

Comment: Right, my markup was pretty sloppy, and others below commented on my poor use of echo.  Both have been fixed in the latest edit.  Thanks for the comments; turns out bad markup was (perhaps surprisingly) not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better way of doing it:

The list of links in your navigation is just that— a list. Instead of using a table, use `ul`, or unordered list. In my example, I also used the `nav` element, which is HTML5. You could easily replace it with a `div`.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice, I did not include the brackets in the markup. This is on purpose. Those brackets do not add to the content or meaning of the site, and should be in the domain of CSS.

This is easily done with pseudo elements:

```
nav a:before {content:'['; display:inline;}
nav a:after {content:']'; display:inline;}
```

You will lose some support with older versions of IE, but everyone, including IE users—and especially those using screen readers or with other accessibility issues—will benefit from the removal of superfluous `span`s. It will also degrade gracefully.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6g4bs/3/).

Comment: That is really cool.  I had no idea I could use content, before, and after.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap [ Home ] and [ Site Map ] in a span. Set the margin of this wrapper to -8px.

http://jsfiddle.net/wkS6H/

*Side note*: Since you are displaying static content echo is inefficient. It causes the server to reproduce the same output every page request.

Comment: I should be wrapping each left/right brace in `<span>` in a loop... but otherwise, I think you're right.

Comment: This solution definitely worked, but bookcasey's seems to be a better general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding on the "navbar" element and the negative bounds on the braces. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/kDq29/1/.

Also note the errors in your HTML markup.

EDIT: I forgot to save my changes from chrome. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

The '] Space [' was caused by left, right, bottom property of braces.

```
span.leftbraces { font-size:25pt; padding: 0px 0px; 
    position:relative; right:-9px;  bottom:-3.75px;}
span.rightbraces { font-size:25pt; padding: 0px 0px; 
    position:relative; left:-9px;  bottom:-3.75px;}
```

Remove the position properties and align the text by its only property.
 - visit : http://jsfiddle.net/fPty7/1